# How to make Ubuntu 18.04 remember the brightness setting after rebooting?

Tags: 18.04, brightness

I'm currently using Ubuntu 18.04.5LTS, and I found that every time I reboot my PC, the brightness automatically goes back to 66%. However, it seems that the volume setting is remembered every time I reboot. Is there any way to make sure that the system remembers the brightness setting before shutting down?

GPU information:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2060    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| N/A   50C    P8     6W /  N/A |    438MiB /  5931MiB |      3%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1292      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 18MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1438      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               51MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2829      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                131MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2942      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell              141MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3385      G   ...AAAAAAAA== --shared-files       92MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: On many system, this is remembered. It depends on the graphical card. You will need to provide information about your hardware. Use "edit" to add the information to your question.

Comment: @vanadium I just edited the question do I need to provide more info?

Comment: Should be good now: the details of the graphical card are there.