# Nvidia doesn't recognize external monitor in On-Demand profile

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Here are the steps I took:

- Disabled Secure Boot in BIOS
- Installed Ubuntu 20.10 opting in to install third-party drivers
- Once complete, ran `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`
- After reboot, confirmed that:

  - `nvidia-driver-460` (latest, recommended) was selected in `Additional Drivers` under `Software & Updates`
  - `NVIDIA On-Demand` was pre-selected in `PRIME Profiles` under `nvidia-settings`
- Plugged in my external monitor and found that:

  - It was shown under `Settings` => `Displays`
  - It was **not** shown in `nvidia-settings`
  - The screen would flash `HDMI No Signal` as if it wasn't connected
  - `dmesg` reported `[drm] Failed to add display topology, DTM TA is not initialized`

The workaround I found was to switch to `NVIDIA (Performance Mode)` and reboot. Now the second screen works, except every 15-20 min the fans suddenly kick in (most of the time they are silent), and I can see high CPU usage either from `gnome-shell` or `Xorg` when running `top`. I'd then run `Alt+F2` => `r` => `Enter` to quiet them down, but these fan spikes repeat regardless which is very distracting.

For now, I reverted to `Using X.Org X server - Nouveau display driver` and purged all `*nvidia*` packages. As a result, my graphics show as `NV168 / AMD Renoir` in the `About` section of `Settings`. I also get weird screen flickers when Ubuntu is booting that I otherwise didn't get with Nvidia drivers. Sometimes when I reboot or power off, Ubuntu would go into a black screen and display `nouveau 0000:01:00.0: tmr: stalled at ffffffffffffffff` messages.

My configuration and specs:

- Ubuntu 20.10 Groovy (default `gdm3` display manager)
- `5.8.0-36-generic` kernel
- AMD Ryzen 7 4800H processor with Radeon graphics
- Nvidia GTX 1660 Ti dedicated graphics card

Things I tried:

- Reinstall Ubuntu with third-party drivers checkbox on
- Reinstall Nvidia drivers from scratch
- Use the latest Nvidia drivers as [this answer from May](https://askubuntu.com/a/1258752/623538) suggests that external monitors are supported in offload mode as of `nvidia-driver-450` and I have `nvidia-driver-460` (`460.32.03`) installed
- Enable experimental hw support in AMDgpu driver as suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1251457)
- Prefix `ExecStartPre` with `/usr/bin/xinit` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1165791)
- Change `options nvidia-drm modeset=` from `1` to `0` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1186190)

Is there anything I'm missing here? Is it possible to make the external monitor work with Nvidia drivers in On-Demand Profile?

Probably related: [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1306358/623538) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1304859/623538).

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the issue you were facing? What makes you suspect this is related to [Second external monitor not waking up (20.04 LTS, GTX 1650 SUPER)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306577/second-external-monitor-not-waking-up-20-04-lts-gtx-1650-super)?

Comment: @jangroth Never mind, I misread your question. Looks like your screen works fine before suspension; in my case, it wasn't connecting in the first place. That said, I'm seeing a lot of graphics-related issues that are traced to the 5.8 kernel, so yours might be related, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue with my RTX 2060. I had already installed the latest Nvidia driver (nvidi-520), but it looks like the latest version of Nvidia drivers are causing several issues. I could solve this by downgrading it.

First, uninstall all Nvidia drivers on your computer:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
```

After that, you should install **nvidia-driver-460-server**. It seems to be the best one until now.

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-460-server
```

Now you should reboot, connect your monitor and it should work.
If not, try to disable the secure boot on your computer.

Best of luck!