# Can't use 2 external monitors on Ubuntu 22.04 using nvidia drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, multiple-monitors, 22.04

I have issues making 2 external monitors work on my Ubuntu 22.04 machine.

**Setup**

- Ubuntu 22.04
- Lenovo Carbon X1 3th Gen
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 1650 Ti
- nvidia-driver-515 (proprietary)
- 2 external monitors connected by USB-C -> DisplayPort

I'm not able to use both of the monitors. If i'm trying to enable the second one, it shows me the message `Changes could not be applied, this could be due to hardware limitation`.

[image]

If i choose `NVIDIA On-Demand` from the NVIDIA settings, it works on all monitors. But it's terribly slow. So i switched to `NVIDIA (Performance Mode)`  but then only one external monitor is working and the other one can't be enabled.

[image]

[image]

**I tried as well...**

- Using another NVIDIA driver, but same result. By using the latest `nvidia-driver-520` all external monitors do not show up anymore at all.
- Removed and purged all drivers and started from scratch. Same result.
- Same result after `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

I'm new to Ubuntu and even Linux. What logs and config outputs could help for helping me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to change the graphic option in bios from `Dynamic graphics` to `Discrete Graphics`. This makes sure, the computer uses the Nvidia card a does not switch to the integrated one to save power.

This solved my issue even with **nvidia-driver-515**.

Answer (score 1):

Please check my answer to a similar question [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1442238/1652196).

I ran into the same issue with my RTX. As you may have guessed it, the problem happens with NVIDIA drivers. Try installing **nvidia-driver-460-server** as I suggested in the other post.

Answer (score 1):

I jumped through all the hoops - restarted about 15 times at least trying all kinds of different drivers.  In my case, this is the only thing that worked:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-`uname -r`
reboot
```

The problem happened to me after an OS update that must have messed up those linux headers.